# Are there any downsides of isomorphic javascript?

Tags: javascript, browserify, serverside-javascript, isomorphism, isomorphic-javascript

As Javascript keeps expanding and covering most of the layers in web development, Isomorphic JS (*writing software that could run either in client or server side*) is growing as a new paradigm for web apps.

[The benefits are clear](http://nerds.airbnb.com/isomorphic-javascript-future-web-apps/) but server side rendering is by far one of the key features of isomorphism.

I haven't play with it very much, and want to implement it into production projects.

So, the question is: is Node mature enough to render server-side for big projects? have you found any *gotchas*? what about maintainability?

Comment: I'm not sure how this question avoids being largely a call for opinions which runs afoul of the stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates) about what LinkedIn is doing interesting.  Client-side rendering for user viewing and server-side rendering for search engines.  All done with Javascript and templates.  I think LinkedIn qualifies as a "big project".

Comment: While interesting, this article is not talking about isomorphic app built on top of Javascript, but a common template engine for client and server. Thanks anyway. And yes, LinkedIn is a "big project" :)

Comment: I will consider rewriting the question if it can be misunderstood...

Comment: @jfriend00. Asking if something has a downside, is just as easily a call for fact as it is a call for opinion. Opinions that are not fact can be down voted. If you don't like the question just down vote it. Or go find questions you can answer.

Comment: @Celess - The actual question was "is Node mature enough to render server-side for big projects?". Since "mature enough" is not defined in any way, the question is either unclear with not enough objective criteria included or it's too broad or it's a solicitation for people's opinions about what that means.  If it was worded as a good stackoverflow question, it probably would have gotten multiple answers because it is in an interesting topic area.  I find it a little ironic that one who has answered 2 questions in the last 3 years here is telling anyone here what to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it was a fair question, and a fair series of questions all of which may have factual answers. Your response was clearly an opinion.

Comment: @Celess - Given the boderline style of the question, I offered as much help as I could with a reference to an article on a related topic (server-side rendering with node.js) which is more than anyone else did and advised the OP that they may need to fix their question to be more in line with the posting guidelines here and more likely to attract a factual answer.  Given what I knew then, I'm not sure what else I could do.  Anyway, no point in debating this further on a 3 year old question.

Comment: @jfriend00 My criticism is valid.